# How to do collpose in new Java API for ElasticSerch 8.x

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In the past, I used RestClient+SearchSourceBuilder to implement the followings.

```json
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "GET /search"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user.id"         
  },
  "from": 0                    
}
```

code like following:

```java
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("xxx(index)");
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.collapse(new CollapseBuilder("user.id"));
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse search = restClient.getRestHighLevelClient().search(searchRequest);
```

However, after I update to ES 8.x and adapt new Java API,

```xml
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
```

Im unable to accomplish the same task by this. The new query code like this

```java
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest;
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest.Builder().index("products").build();

        SearchResponse<Product> search =
                client.search(
                        request,
                        Product.class
                );
        List<Hit<Product>> hits = search.hits().hits();
```

Since it used different different SearchRequest from different denpendency, I dont know how to create a collapse builder for it and I searched the "whole" internet but got nothing for this new Java Client API.

BTW, the reason I want to use `collapse` is because I want to remove the duplicate results from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest.Builder().index("movies")
        .from(0)
        .query(new Query.Builder().match(new MatchQuery.Builder().field("message").query("any_text").build()).build())
        .collapse(new FieldCollapse.Builder().field("user.id").build())
        .build();
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Are there any detailed docs I can refer to explore all features of this new Client?

Comment: I read a bit [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html) but usually I figure it out on my own. I also go a lot in the git of the new java client.